# Ejecutar condicional solo por única vez cada vez que se crea el fragmento - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Estoy iniciando mi aplicación de la siguiente forma:

```js
class verification_fragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.verification_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        val a = true
        
        if(a){
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentob)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Estoy tratando de que al iniciar el fragmento verifique si **a = true** y navegue al siguiente fragmento **fragmentob** si se cumple dicha condicional. Hasta esa parte todo está bien, con normalidad me pasa al siguiente fragmento. Pero cuando quiero regresar de **fragmentob** a **verification_fragment** se vuelve a ejecutar la condicional y siempre me envia al **fragmentob** en un bucle de navegación de **verification_fragment** a **fragmentob**, mi duda es la siguiente ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esa condicional solo se ejecute una sola vez al iniciar la aplicación?. Estoy usando NavigationComponents en Android. Si alguien me podría guiar, le agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Una solución rápida es que "val a" la declares en el scope de la clase a true y, cuando entres en el if (a) entonces la pones a false.  De esta manera, cuando se recree la vista, ya no entrará en la condición por ser false.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías intentar alguna de las siguientes soluciones.

1. Podrías crear una variable llamada `firstTime` de tipo booleano en un viewModel. entonces en un inicio esta variable tendrá el valor de true, luego de entrar a la condicional , cambias el valor de esta variable a false. De este modo ya no tendrás el bucle que mencionas.
2. Ahora también lo puedes trabajar con una variable estática que puede estar en tu fragment.

   ```
   class verification_fragment : Fragment() {

   companion object {
       var FLAG = true
   }

   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.verification_fragment, container, false)
   }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


       if(FLAG){
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentob)
           FLAG = false
       }

   }
   ```
3. La opción que yo elegiría sera esta, simplemente ten has el pase de fragment en el método `onCreate()`, recordemos el lifecycle del fragment, ese método solo se ejecuta la primera vez, cuando haces back se ejecuta el `onViewcreated()` y `onCreateView` mas no `onCreate`. Entonces si implementas tu lógica en ese método, si haces back ya no se volverá a ejecutar

   ```
   class verification_fragment : Fragment() {

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragmentob)
       }
   }
   ```

Espero te ayude :)